# How to add tags from a UITableView to another UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 `ViewControllers` and each ViewController have a `UITableView`.
In the MainViewController I have few rows and I want to add for each row different Tags from the second ViewController.
My tags are saved in a Dictionary (I don't know if is the best way but I was thinking that maybe I will avoid to append a tag twice using a Dict instead of Array).
The problem is that I don't append correctly the selected tags and I don't know how I should do it.
Here I've created a small project which reflect my issue: [https://github.com/tygruletz/AppendTagsToCells](https://github.com/tygruletz/AppendCommentsToCells)

Here is the code for Main VC:

```
class ChecklistVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionsTableView: UITableView!

    //Properties
    lazy var itemSections: [ChecklistItemSection] = {
        return ChecklistItemSection.checklistItemSections()
    }()
    var lastIndexPath: IndexPath!
    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        questionsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ChecklistVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let itemCategory = itemSections[section]
        return itemCategory.checklistItems.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return itemSections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checklistCell", for: indexPath) as! ChecklistCell

        let itemCategory = itemSections[indexPath.section]
        let item = itemCategory.checklistItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configCell(item)

        cell.vehicleCommentLabel.text = item.vehicleComment
        cell.trailerCommentLabel.text = item.trailerComment

        cell.tagNameLabel.text = item.vehicleTags[indexPath.row]?.name

        return cell
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goChecklistAddComment" {
            let addCommentVC = segue.destination as! ChecklistAddCommentVC
            addCommentVC.delegate = self
        }

        if segue.identifier == "goChecklistAddTag" {
            let checklistAddTag = segue.destination as! ChecklistAddTagVC

            checklistAddTag.indexForSelectedRow = self.selectedIndexPath

            checklistAddTag.tagsCallback = { result in
                print("result: \(result)")
                let item = self.itemSections[self.lastIndexPath.section].checklistItems[self.lastIndexPath.row]
                item.vehicleTags = result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Tags ViewController:

```
class ChecklistAddTagVC: UIViewController {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var tagsTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tagsTableView: UITableView!

    // Properties
    var tagsDictionary: [Int: Tag] = [:]
    var tagsAdded: [Int:Tag] = [:]
    var tagsCallback: (([Int:Tag]) -> ())?
    var indexForSelectedRow: IndexPath!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tagsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        tagsDictionary = [
            1: Tag(remoteID: 1, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag1", colour: "red"),
            2: Tag(remoteID: 2, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag2", colour: "blue"),
            3: Tag(remoteID: 3, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag3", colour: "orange"),
            4: Tag(remoteID: 4, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag4", colour: "black")
        ]

        print("Received index for SelectedRow: \(indexForSelectedRow ?? IndexPath())")
    }
}

extension ChecklistAddTagVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tagsDictionary.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defectAndDamageTagCell", for: indexPath) as! ChecklistAddTagCell
        cell.configCell()
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.tagNameLabel.text = tagsDictionary[indexPath.row + 1]?.name.capitalized
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 60
    }
}

extension ChecklistAddTagVC: ChecklistAddTagCellDelegate{

    // When the user press Add Tag then will be added in a dictionary and sent to ChecklistVC using a callback closure.
    func addTagBtnPressed(button: UIButton, tagLabel: UILabel) {

        if button.currentTitle == "+"{
            button.setTitle("-", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            tagLabel.textColor = UIColor.orange
            tagsAdded = [0: Tag(remoteID: 1, categoryID: 1, name: tagLabel.text ?? String(), colour: "red")]
            print(tagsAdded[0]?.name ?? String())
            tagsCallback?(tagsAdded)
        }
        else{
            button.setTitle("+", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            tagLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            tagsAdded.removeValue(forKey: 0)
            print(tagsAdded)
            tagsCallback?(tagsAdded)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a capture with my issue:

[image]

Thank you for reading this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it !

The solution is below. Also you can find the completed project at this link:
https://github.com/tygruletz/AppendCommentsToCells

MainVC:

```
class ChecklistVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionsTableView: UITableView!

    //Properties
    lazy var itemSections: [ChecklistItemSection] = {
        return ChecklistItemSection.checklistItemSections()
    }()
    var lastIndexPath: IndexPath!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        questionsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ChecklistVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let itemCategory = itemSections[section]
        return itemCategory.checklistItems.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return itemSections.count
    }

    // Set the header of each section
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        let checklistItemCategory = itemSections[section]
        return checklistItemCategory.name.uppercased()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "checklistCell", for: indexPath) as! ChecklistCell

        let itemCategory = itemSections[indexPath.section]
        let item = itemCategory.checklistItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configCell(item)

        cell.vehicleCommentLabel.text = item.vehicleComment
        cell.trailerCommentLabel.text = item.trailerComment

        let sortedTagNames = item.vehicleTags.keys.sorted(by: {$0 < $1}).compactMap({ item.vehicleTags[$0]})

        print("Sorted tag names: \(sortedTagNames.map {$0.name})")

        let joinedTagNames = sortedTagNames.map { $0.name}.joined(separator: ", ")

        cell.tagNameLabel.text = joinedTagNames

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 150
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goChecklistAddComment" {
            let addCommentVC = segue.destination as! ChecklistAddCommentVC
            addCommentVC.delegate = self
        }

        if segue.identifier == "goChecklistAddTag" {
            let addTagVC = segue.destination as! ChecklistAddTagVC
            addTagVC.delegate = self
            addTagVC.addedTags = itemSections[lastIndexPath.section].checklistItems[lastIndexPath.row].vehicleTags
        }
    }
}

extension ChecklistVC: ChecklistCellDelegate {
    func tapGestureOnCell(_ cell: ChecklistCell) {

        showOptionsOnCellTapped(questionsTableView.indexPath(for: cell)!)
    }

    func showOptionsOnCellTapped(_ indexPath: IndexPath){

        let addComment = UIAlertAction(title: " Add Comment", style: .default) { action in
            self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goChecklistAddComment", sender: nil)
        }

        let addTag = UIAlertAction(title: " Add Tag ⤵", style: .default) { action in
            self.showOptionsForAddTag(indexPath)
        }

        let actionSheet = configureActionSheet()
        actionSheet.addAction(addComment)
        actionSheet.addAction(addTag)

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // A menu from where the user can choose to add tags for Vehicle or Trailer
    func showOptionsForAddTag(_ indexPath: IndexPath){

        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
        let addVehicleTag = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Vehicle tag", style: .default) { action in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goChecklistAddTag", sender: nil)
        }
        let addTrailerTag = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Trailer tag", style: .default) { action in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goChecklistAddTag", sender: nil)
        }
        let actionSheet = configureActionSheet()
        actionSheet.addAction(addVehicleTag)
        actionSheet.addAction(addTrailerTag)
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configureActionSheet() -> UIAlertController {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
        }

        return actionSheet
    }
}

// Receive Comments from ChecklistAddCommentVC using the Delegate Pattern
extension ChecklistVC: ChecklistAddCommentDelegate {

    func receiveVehicleComment(vehicleComment: String?, trailerComment: String?) {

        let item = itemSections[lastIndexPath.section].checklistItems[lastIndexPath.row]
        item.vehicleComment = vehicleComment ?? String()
        item.trailerComment = trailerComment ?? String()

        questionsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// Receive Tags from ChecklistAddTagVC using the Delegate Pattern
extension ChecklistVC: ChecklistAddTagVCDelegate{

    func receiveAddedTags(tags: [Int : Tag]) {

        let item = self.itemSections[self.lastIndexPath.section].checklistItems[self.lastIndexPath.row]
        item.vehicleTags = tags
    }
}
```

AddTagsVC:

```
protocol ChecklistAddTagVCDelegate {
    func receiveAddedTags(tags: [Int: Tag])
}

class ChecklistAddTagVC: UIViewController {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var tagsTableView: UITableView!

    // Properties
    var tagsDictionary: [Int: Tag] = [:]
    var addedTags: [Int: Tag] = [:]
    var delegate: ChecklistAddTagVCDelegate?
    var indexPathForBtn: IndexPath!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tagsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        tagsDictionary = [
            1: Tag(remoteID: 1, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag1", color: "red"),
            2: Tag(remoteID: 2, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag2", color: "blue"),
            3: Tag(remoteID: 3, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag3", color: "orange"),
            4: Tag(remoteID: 4, categoryID: 1, name: "Tag4", color: "black")
        ]
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        print("Added tags: \(addedTags.map {$1.name})")

        setupButtons()

        tagsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ChecklistAddTagVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tagsDictionary.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defectAndDamageTagCell", for: indexPath) as! ChecklistAddTagCell
        cell.configCell()
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.tagNameLabel.text = tagsDictionary[indexPath.row + 1]?.name.capitalized
        indexPathForBtn = indexPath

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 60
    }
}

extension ChecklistAddTagVC: ChecklistAddTagCellDelegate{

    // When the user press Add Tag then will be added in a dictionary and sent to ChecklistVC using a callback closure.
    func addTagBtnPressed(button: UIButton, tagLabel: UILabel) {

        let buttonPosition: CGPoint = button.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tagsTableView)
        let indexPath = tagsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        let indexPathForBtn: Int = indexPath?.row ?? 0
        let tag: Tag = tagsDictionary[indexPathForBtn + 1] ?? Tag(remoteID: 0, categoryID: 0, name: String(), color: String())

        if button.currentTitle == "+"{
            button.setTitle("-", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            tagLabel.textColor = UIColor.orange

            // Add selected tag to Dictionary when the user press +
            addedTags[tag.remoteID] = tag
        }
        else{
            button.setTitle("+", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            tagLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

            // Delete selected tag from Dictionary when the user press -
            addedTags.removeValue(forKey: tag.remoteID)
        }
        // Send the Dictionary to ChecklistVC
        if delegate != nil{
            delegate?.receiveAddedTags(tags: addedTags)
        }
        print("\n ****** UPDATED DICTIONARY ******")
        print(addedTags.map {"key: \($1.remoteID) - name: \($1.name)"})
    }

    // Setup the state of the buttons and also the color of the buttons to be orange if that Tag exist in `addedTags` dictionary.
    func setupButtons(){

        for eachAddedTag in addedTags {

            if eachAddedTag.value.remoteID == tagsDictionary[1]?.remoteID {

                print(eachAddedTag)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to handle tableview:didselectrowatindexpath instead of using the segue and on didselectrowatindexpath show the add tag vc.

Comment: Unfortunately the requirements for flow are like this. The user hold tap on a cell and a menu PopUp and from there the user will click on Add Tag.